# For independent events with 3 events A,B,C

Tags: probability

If events A,B,C are independent with $Pr(A)=x$, $Pr(B)=y$ and $Pr(C)=z$ then what is the probability that exactly two of the three events occur?  I'm just confused on how it would look on a venn diagram.  I know from a previous problem that the the probability that exactly one occurs is

$$Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)-2Pr(A)Pr(B)-2Pr(A)Pr(C)-2Pr(B)P(C)+3Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C)$$

$$=x+y+z-2xy-2xz-2yz+3xyz$$

What would the formula look like for exactly two events out of the three?

Comment: It can happen in $3$ different ways. Note that for example the probability of $A$ and $B$ but not $C$ is $xy(1-z)$.  Add up.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider each instance in which two of these three events occur. That is, you must define the sample space.

We can have: xy, xz, yz

So you must find: 
$$xy(1-z)+xz(1-y)+yz(1-x)$$

The terms of the form $(1-...)$ are giving the probability of that particular event not occurring.